# xml a R base de datos, diferentes niveles

Tags: base-de-datos, xml, r

Tengo este código xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<sct type="detail" version="0.1">
-<serviceLevelSegments timestamp="2017-10-25T11:45:44Z">
<Segment travelTimeMinutes="0.387" c-value="100" score="30" reference="85" 
average="77" speed="95" code="447332188"/>
-<Segment travelTimeMinutes="0.597" c-value="100" score="30" reference="85" 
average="77" speed="85" code="447332203">
<SubSegment speed="95" PkEnd="782.112" PkIni="781.9" offset="0,212"/>
<SubSegment speed="77" PkEnd="782.746" offset="635,846" pkIni="782.535"/>
</Segment>
</serviceLevelSegments>
</sct>
```

Y quiero obtener una tabla con todos los atributos (de todos los niveles). Sería una tabla como esta:

```
                          Value1      Value2     Value3     ...
timestamp
code
travelTimeMinutes
c-value
score
reference
average
speed (from Segment)
speed (from SubSegment)
PkEnd
PkIni
offset
```

En las celdas vacías me gustaría que pusiera: "NA".

Sólo he conseguido obtener una tabla separada para cada nivel (serviceLevelSegments, Segment o SubSegment por separado). Por ejemplo, para obtener la tabla para el nivel SubSegment, he encontrado este código:

```
library(XML)
arch = "file.xml" #code in xml
input <- xmlParse(arch)
nodes <- getNodeSet(input,"//SubSegment")
all_parameters <- sapply(nodes, xmlAttrs)
all_parameters
```

Pero sólo obtengo una tabla con estos atributos (en campo filas): speed, offset, PkIni, PkEnd. Y necesito todos los atributos que salen en el código.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Ana, estoy más familiarizado con [`xml2`](https://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiuuuT_zqfXAhWDhJAKHcbdC_0QFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcran.r-project.org%2Fweb%2Fpackages%2Fxml2%2Fxml2.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0XZOV8g7qugY7WFhlD20nY), por lo que te voy a proponer una solución usando este paquete. Para instalarlo: `install.packages("xml2")` en la consola.

```
library(xml2)

xmlText <- '<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <sct type="detail" version="0.1">
        <serviceLevelSegments timestamp="2017-10-25T11:45:44Z">
            <Segment travelTimeMinutes="0.387" c-value="100" score="30" reference="85" 
            average="77" speed="95" code="447332188"/>
            <Segment travelTimeMinutes="0.597" c-value="100" score="30" reference="85" 
            average="77" speed="85" code="447332203">
                <SubSegment speed="95" PkEnd="782.112" PkIni="781.9" offset="0,212"/>
                <SubSegment speed="77" PkEnd="782.746" offset="635,846" pkIni="782.535"/>
            </Segment>
        </serviceLevelSegments>
    </sct>'

xml <- read_xml(xmlText)

niveles <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3), 
                      node=c('serviceLevelSegments', 'Segment', 'SubSegment'))

df <- data.frame()
colvar <- rep(NA,nrow(niveles))
for (n in xml_find_all(xml, ".//*")) {
    for (a in names(xml_attrs(n))) {
        df <- rbind(df, c(cbind(xml_name(n), a), colvar), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
        df[nrow(df),!is.na(c(NA,NA,niveles[match(niveles$node,xml_name(n)),1]))] <- xml_attr(n,a)
    }
}
colnames(df) <- c("nodo", "attr",paste0("Valor",1:nrow(niveles)))
df
```

La Salida:

```
                   nodo              attr               Valor1    Valor2  Valor3
1  serviceLevelSegments         timestamp 2017-10-25T11:45:44Z      <NA>    <NA>
2               Segment travelTimeMinutes                 <NA>     0.387    <NA>
3               Segment           c-value                 <NA>       100    <NA>
4               Segment             score                 <NA>        30    <NA>
5               Segment         reference                 <NA>        85    <NA>
6               Segment           average                 <NA>        77    <NA>
7               Segment             speed                 <NA>        95    <NA>
8               Segment              code                 <NA> 447332188    <NA>
9               Segment travelTimeMinutes                 <NA>     0.597    <NA>
10              Segment           c-value                 <NA>       100    <NA>
11              Segment             score                 <NA>        30    <NA>
12              Segment         reference                 <NA>        85    <NA>
13              Segment           average                 <NA>        77    <NA>
14              Segment             speed                 <NA>        85    <NA>
15              Segment              code                 <NA> 447332203    <NA>
16           SubSegment             speed                 <NA>      <NA>      95
17           SubSegment             PkEnd                 <NA>      <NA> 782.112
18           SubSegment             PkIni                 <NA>      <NA>   781.9
19           SubSegment            offset                 <NA>      <NA>   0,212
20           SubSegment             speed                 <NA>      <NA>      77
21           SubSegment             PkEnd                 <NA>      <NA> 782.746
22           SubSegment            offset                 <NA>      <NA> 635,846
23           SubSegment             pkIni                 <NA>      <NA> 782.535
```

Agregué el nodo para que sea más claro de entender, pero si quieres quedarte solo con los atributos, simplemente filtras la columna.

Un poco de explicación:

- En primer lugar, definimos cuales son los nodos que determinan cada nivel, en el orden que corresponden. Eventualmente se podría ver de determinar los "niveles" de forma dinámica, pero para no complicar el ejemplo ya que en tu caso los nodos son conocidos de antemano hacemos:

  ```
  niveles <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3), 
                    node=c('serviceLevelSegments', 'Segment', 'SubSegment'))
  ```
- Luego iteramos por todos los nodos `xml_find_all(xml, ".//*")` y por todos los atributos de cada uno de estos: `names(xml_attrs(n))`
- Agregamos una nueva fila al `data.frame` con las columnas de `nodo`, `atributo` y una columna adicional para el valor por cada nivel: `df <- rbind(df, c(cbind(xml_name(n), a), colvar), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`
- El valor del atributo lo ingresamos en la columna que corresponde según el nivel en que estamos: `df[nrow(df),!is.na(c(NA,NA,niveles[match(niveles$node,xml_name(n)),1]))] <- xml_attr(n,a)`
- Y por último,como detalle estético, renombramos las columnas: `colnames(df) <- c("nodo", "attr",paste0("Valor",1:nrow(niveles)))`

Comment: Hola Patricio, muchas gracias. Lo que pasa es que con tu código me sale algo diferente a lo que indicas, lo que me sale es la tabla vacía, te adjunto una foto en una respuesta a mi pregunta.  No sé qué problema puede haber, ya que no me sale ningún error.

Comment: Hola Patricio, gracias, te contesto aquí porque me han borrado la respuesta. Adjunto el link del código en ExpireBox: https://expirebox.com/download/b5bdc28fcd1ee305db20ed2bf7217818.html

Comment: @Ana, acabo de verificar leyendo directamente el archivo que compartiste mediante `xml <- read_xml("sct_detail_proposed.xml")` y el ejemplo de mi respuesta funciona tal cual está explicado y con la misma salida. Actualiza por las dudas el paquete xml2 `update.packages("xml2")` y vuelve a copiar exactamente el código de mi respuesta para verificar. Saludos.

Comment: Hola Patricio, sigue saliéndome la tabla vacía, he probado varias cosas y nada. No te preocupes, gracias de todas formas!